# Understanding how LAMMPS manages files and directories

Tags: installed-programs

I installed LAMMPS following the instructions, and have some questions. These are the instructions ([Pre-built Ubuntu Linux executables](http://lammps.sandia.gov/download.html#ubuntu)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gladky-anton/lammps
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install lammps-daily
```

The program is run doing:

```
lammps-daily < in.lj
```

---

These are the questions:

1. From which directory must a job be submitted to run?
2. How can I set or where I can find the outputs of the jobs submitted?
3. Where are the scripts for running the program?

I looked at the location of LAMMPS related files and found these: `/usr/bin/lammps-daily` (program) and two folders on `/usr/share/docs/lammps-daily`, `/usr/share/docs/lammps-docs`. Maybe I'm missing some basic Operative System functioning, not reading the program manual, or should I browse between these files?

Comment: Should I follow something like this: http://sourceforge.net/p/lammps/mailman/message/22519360/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From which directory must a job be submitted to run?

Once you've installed the program, you can invoke it from any directory by:

`lmp_linux < /path/to/your/inputfile.txt`

where the `inputfile.txt` is the script you want to run. [Here's](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_commands.html) some information on how to write input scripts.

> How can I set/where I can find the outputs of the jobs submitted?

You can use the below option:

> -log file

to specify a log file for LAMMPS to write status information to. In one-partition mode, if the switch is not used, LAMMPS writes to the file `log.lammps`. If this switch is used, LAMMPS writes to the specified file.

> Where are the scripts for running the program?

Not exactly sure what you mean by scripts here. If you are taking about input scripts, [here](https://icme.hpc.msstate.edu/mediawiki/index.php/LAMMPS_tutorials) there are few example scripts in the `bench` and `example` directories (of the unzipped source). You can see more tutorials [here](https://icme.hpc.msstate.edu/mediawiki/index.php/LAMMPS_tutorials).

Comment: Appreciate it, I didn't download the source itself (big ignorance I know). Once downloaded I will try this and then give feedback.