# Where is src/make?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

I'm Confused. I need to run a program (see [This previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720272/understanding-how-lammps-manages-files-and-directories) for details) and the instructions says "you can typically use the Makefile.mpi or Makefile.serial files in src/MAKE by typing one of these lines (from the src dir):"

```
make mpi
make serial
```

But I don't know where is src/MAKE.

Comment: What instructions?  Are you compiling from source?

Comment: It should work without manually compiling for what I understand, here are the instructions: http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_start.html (In Section 2.2)

Comment: Hint: why does your title contain a / and the body not contain a / in front of src. (the latter is the correct one ;) src/make relative to the software to install ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First download the [source tarball](http://lammps.sandia.gov/download.html#tar), untar it and you'll find a bunch of directories including `src`. `make` should be inside this directory. You can `cd` into `src` and then execute `make` commands.

See the section 2.1 of the [instructions](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_start.html) for more details on unzipping tarballs, source directory structure etc.